# Compressing post requests sent to Gmail API

Tags: gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

As recommended [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch), I'm using batch requests in the Gmail API. I've noticed that the actual requests are getting pretty big, so I thought of compressing them using gzip.
I've got it to work up to the point that I see the compressed POST request going out on Fiddler, but I get a Bad Request message back:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Bad Request</H1>
<H2>Error 400</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Is this simply not supported in the Gmail API, or am I overlooking something?

Here is the code (I'm using C# as you can see):

```
    private static async Task<StreamContent> CompressedContent(HttpContent content)
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        using (System.IO.Compression.GZipStream gzip = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms,
                            System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            await content.CopyToAsync(gzip).OnThreadPool();
            await gzip.FlushAsync();
        }
        ms.Position = 0;

        StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(ms);
        streamContent.Headers.ContentType = content.Headers.ContentType;
        streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        return streamContent;
    }

    private async Task<string> GetResponseItemResult(string batchUri, MultipartContent cont, bool compressed = false)
    { 
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip }))
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(batchUri),
            Method = HttpMethod.Post
        })
        {
            if (compressed)
                request.Content = await CompressedContent(cont);
            else
                request.Content = cont;

            //Authentication stuff removed
            //...

            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).OnThreadPool();

            //Error handling removed
            //...
            return await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

    }
```

If I don't use compression, but just pass the content straight as it is, it works fine.
As said before, the actual content is a batch request and Fiddler can read it fine, compressed or uncompressed.

Comment: gzip is supported. Show your code.

Comment: @JayLee: edited the post to include the code.

Comment: First off, use the API Client library. It implements stuff like compression for you https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/.

Answer (score 0):

The API Client library still has an [open bug](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/409) exactly about this issue, no?

And the source contains the following comment:

```
// Batch request currently doesn't support GZip. Uncomment when the issue will be resolved.
```

I guess that settles it?